# How to use regular expression for Cookies in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am missing something, now sure how to pass the Cookies if its expecting.

[image: Getting error in login page.]
[image: Below the session ids passed in cookie section]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need to perform manual correlation of the cookies, [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) should take care of them automatically.

If it doesn't:

- Try setting "Cookie Policy" to something less restrictive, i.e. `netscape`

  [image]
- Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

  ```
  CookieManager.check.cookies=false
  ```
- If you need to store cookies as JMeter Variables add the next line to the *user.properties* file:

  ```
  CookieManager.save.cookies=true
  ```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. The above properties will "tell" JMeter to:

1. Not to check cookies and accept anything
2. Save cookies into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you will be able to access them as:

   - `${COOKIE_mySessionId}`
   - `${COOKIE_ZCC}`

Check [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) for more Cookie Manager tips and tricks

However most probably your problem is not connected with cookies, looking into [Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed) most probably your Viewstate [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I fixed the error by putting the path correctly in Login page: `login_frame_ajax.aspx`

For now I am getting 302 response code. The yellow padding error is gone from page.